# method PUT of AJAX with Laravel 9

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, methods, request

I am learning laravel, when I want to update an object and I use ajax to send data to update action with put method (routing also to set) but my update action side is not receiving it request that ajax send like so
! Code

```
<form id="formEdit" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')
    <div class="card-body">
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input value="{{$role->name ?? ''}}" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter name">
     </div>
    </div>
  <!-- /.card-body -->

   <div class="card-footer">
     <button type="submit" class="float-right btn btn-primary">Lưu lại</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

````
```
$.ajaxSetup({
 headers: {
 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
 }
});

function sendAjax(url, formData, type, method = 'post'){
var result =  $.ajax({
url: url,
method: method,
typeData: 'json',
data: formData,
processData: false,
contentType: false,
async: false
});
return resultAjax(result, type);
}```
```
<script>
$('#formEdit').submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var eleValidate = ['name'];
  var data = new FormData($('#formEdit')[0]);
  var url = "{{route('role.update', $role->id)}}";
  var result = sendAjax(url, data, 'edit', 'put');
  if(result){
    renderError(result, eleValidate);
  }else{
    removeError(eleValidate, 'formEdit');
 }
 });        
</script>
```
````

```
Route::put('/role/update/{id}', 'update')->name('role.update');
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        if($request->ajax()){
            $role = RoleModel::find($id);
            dd($request);
        }
        
    }
```

[Payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aoh6W.jpg)

[dd($request)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/io5xP.jpg)

Comment: `typeData` in your jQuery ajax should be `dataType: "json",`

Comment: @AnujShrestha I have also tried and still get the same result as above